# Questions about the company

Tags: lego-group

I would like someone to answer a lot of questions  for a school project that i'm doing, if you can get someone to answer all these questions that'd be great.

- What work ethic, qualities and attributes dose the company look for in their employees and why?
- What academic skills do they want in their employees to have AND how do they use this on a daily basis?
- What types of manufacturing equipment/machinery dose their company use most>?
- What do each of these machinery do?
- What training dose an enployee need in order to use the the equipment/machinery
- What education is required for an entry-level position?
- what education is required for a management position?
- What is the salary (or salary range) for a management position?
- What skills, benchmarks , or abilities are key to advancement from entry-level position to management level positions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the Lego Group and some of these questions can only be answered by contacting them. Some of the questions might be answered by a google search though.

Comment: None of us on this website is affiliated with the LEGO company, so we can't answer these questions. You could, however, ask LEGO directly, via their customer service: https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service/

Comment: Most of these Exchange websites prefer one question per post.